# Output resets when after closing/reopening the file

Tags: manipulate, output

I've been having an issue in a project I am working on for a demonstration that involves a manipulate containing buttons that influence local variables. In essence, the problem is demonstrated by this piece of code:

```
Manipulate[DynamicModule[{T = 5},

Dynamic[Panel[Row[{T, Spacer[50], Button["T", T = T + 1]}]]]], {x, 
1, 4}]
```

Before Closing:

[image]

After Reopening:

[image]

It works fine as far as functionality, but when I try to create a thumbnail and snapshot with the output, the values displayed are not saved if I close and reopen the file (in the case of this program, the display of of T would be reset to 5). How can I get around this?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're after. Is it that you want to close the notebook containing your code (or quit Mathematica for that matter), but have it remember state on reopening? As in you make a pic of the state, associate it with the notebook, and when opened it matches the pic? Then you'll need to save the state and read it on open, via things like `Save`, `Get`, `Dumpsave`, `Dumpget`, `Put`, among others, or just write/read from an associated file on close/open...

Comment: Change the order of `DynamicModule` and `Manipulate`: so `DynamicModule[{T=5}, Manipulate[...`. Also, remember that everything in `Manipulate` is effectively wrapped in `Dynamic`. Another point, the less `Dynamic` the better so in this case I'd use `Dynamic[T], Spacer...` without `Dynamic` on `Panel`.

Comment: You can use this `DynamicModule[{x = 5},
 Dynamic[Print@1; x]]` to see that after reopening `1` will be printed, `Dynamic` recreates the content and in your case it is `DynamicModule[{T=5}...`.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code mixes things up unfortunately. What you need to do is stick with `DynamicModule`, in which case `Manipulate` is redundant, or stick with `Manipulate` in which case `DynamicModule` is redundant. Personally I don't like `Manipulate` at all and would recommend `DynamicModule`.

```
DynamicModule[{T = 5}, 
 Dynamic[Panel[Row[{T, Spacer[50], Button["T", T = T + 1]}]]]]
```

If you must use `Manipulate` then

```
Manipulate[
 Panel[Row[{T, Spacer[50], Button["T", T = T + 1]}]], {x, 1, 4}, {T, 
  5, None}]
```

In both the above examples the value of `T` is preserved across sessions. The screen grab is taken after closing Mma and reopening.

[image]

For your real world example I would recommend paying close attention to the syntax colouring so you can identify which variables belong to what and will have values preserved.